# Need to display record horizontally by date

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, logic

i have the following mysql table with data in it. Table with data is shown in the photo below:

[image]

I want to display the record in html table like this:

[image]

While it displays record like the following:

[image]

I have the following code for this:

```
 <?php
 $year = intval($_POST['year']);
 $month = (intval($_POST['month']) < 10 && strlen($_POST['month']) < 2) ? '0'.intval($_POST['month']):intval($_POST['month']);
 $sql = "SELECT sno,file_path,bench_sno,causelist_date,date_entry 
         FROM phc_causelists 
         WHERE YEAR(causelist_date) = :year AND MONTH(causelist_date) = :month ORDER BY causelist_date DESC";
 $aryList = array(':year'=>$year,':month'=>$month);
 if($db->dbQuery($sql,$aryList)){
 ?>

 <strong>Causelists for the month of <?php echo($method->getMonthName(intval($month)).' '.intval($year)); ?> </strong>
 <table class="table table-bordered">
 <?php
 foreach($db->getRecordSet($sql,$aryList) as $row){
    ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo($row['causelist_date']); ?></td>
        <td><?php if($row['bench_sno'] == '1'){ ?>
          <a href="<?php echo($method->baseURL()); ?>/causeLists/<?php echo($row['file_path']); ?>">Peshawar High Court</a>
          <?php } ?></td>
        <td><?php if($row['bench_sno'] == '2'){ ?>
          <a href="<?php echo($method->baseURL()); ?>/causeLists/<?php echo($row['file_path']); ?>">Abbottabad</a>
          <?php } ?></td>
        <td><?php if($row['bench_sno'] == '3'){ ?>
          <a href="<?php echo($method->baseURL()); ?>/causeLists/<?php echo($row['file_path']); ?>">D.I.Khan</a>
          <?php } ?></td>
        <td><?php if($row['bench_sno'] == '4'){ ?>
          <a href="<?php echo($method->baseURL()); ?>/causeLists/<?php echo($row['file_path']); ?>">Mingora</a>
          <?php } ?></td>
        <td><?php if($row['bench_sno'] == '5'){ ?>
          <a href="<?php echo($method->baseURL()); ?>/causeLists/<?php echo($row['file_path']); ?>">Bannu</a>
          <?php } ?></td>
      </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
 </table>
 <?php
 }
  ?>
```

Comment: why u put if condition **<?php if($row['bench_sno'] == '1'){**   ?

Comment: i have another table which contains the labels for bench_sno. where for label "PHC" i have sno = 1, sno 2 for Abbottabad etc

Comment: i guess your table structure is mismatched with your php if condition.

Comment: i noticed, you have started your **<td>** tag and inside it you have your condition .. i guess it is causing this weird behavior of your table.

Comment: your ˋforeachˋ loop generates one ˋtrˋ per database record. You are missing something that groups per date.

Comment: @PaulH i have only 5 benches in my table i.e. 1,2,3,4 and 5 so i need to run the loop and have to hard code the tr and td accordingly but the loop is running and generating TR for each and every record in its iteration

Comment: Yes, but you should group by date (either in SQL or PHP) and output one TR per date, not per database record.

Comment: @PaulH yes you are right and its the point where i am stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work. With minimal changes, it groups the dates, then loops foreach date.

```
<?php
foreach($db->getRecordSet($sql,$aryList) as $row){
    // build an array of dates 
    //   containing for each date an array of bench_sno
    $dates[$row['causelist_date']][$row['bench_sno']] = $row['filepath'];
}
foreach($dates as $date=>$row) {
?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo($date); ?></td>
    <td><?php if(isset($row['1'])){ ?> 
      <a href="<?php echo($method->baseURL()); ?>/causeLists/<?php echo($row['1']); ?>">Peshawar High Court</a>
      <?php } ?></td>
    <td><?php if(isset($row['2'])){ ?>
      <a href="<?php echo($method->baseURL()); ?>/causeLists/<?php echo($row['2']); ?>">Abbottabad</a>
      <?php } ?></td>
    <td><?php if(isset($row['3'])){ ?>
      <a href="<?php echo($method->baseURL()); ?>/causeLists/<?php echo($row['3']); ?>">D.I.Khan</a>
      <?php } ?></td>
    <td><?php if(isset($row['4'])){ ?>
      <a href="<?php echo($method->baseURL()); ?>/causeLists/<?php echo($row['4']); ?>">Mingora</a>
      <?php } ?></td>
    <td><?php if(isset($row['5'])){ ?>
      <a href="<?php echo($method->baseURL()); ?>/causeLists/<?php echo($row['5']); ?>">Bannu</a>
      <?php } ?></td>
  </tr>
<?php
}
?>
```

Alternatively, I like to avoid repeating code and use alternative control syntax in templates like this:

```
<?php
foreach($db->getRecordSet($sql,$aryList) as $row) {
    // build an array of dates 
    //   containing for each date an array of bench_sno
    $dates[$row['causelist_date']][$row['bench_sno']] = $row['filepath'];
}
$bench_snos[
    '1' => 'Peshawar High Court',
    '2' => 'Abbottabad',
    '3' => 'D.I.Khan',
    '4' => 'Mingora',
    '5' => 'Bannu',
];
foreach($dates as $date=>$row) :
?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $date ?></td>
    <?php foreach ($bench_snos as $no=>$bench_sno) : ?>
    <td><?php if (isset($row[$no])) : ?> 
      <a href="<?php echo $method->baseURL() ?>/causeLists/<?php echo $row[$no] ?>"><?php echo $bench_sno ?></a>
      <?php endif //isset ?>
    </td>
    <?php endfor //$bench_snos ?>
  </tr>
<?php endfor // $dates ?>
```

Comment: it does not return anything... while print_r() return only 0,1,6,-

Comment: I corrected a bug.
sorry, it what? print_r of what? You should be able to debug with 9 years experience?

Comment: you did a wonderful job you know. There is only one bug you have forgotten ")" in each if(isset($row['1']). While now it rocks. thanks a lot

Comment: Glad I could help, I found your question well documented, easy to understand and limited scope.

Comment: Ohhh there is a bug in the code: i have used $row['file_path'] in the code, which is now not working because we have closed the first loop. How to access that record now? any idea?

Comment: It does not return anything now?

Comment: Done, i have replace the line in the first loop by : $dates[$row['causelist_date']][$row['bench_sno']] = $row['file_path'] != ""?$row['file_path']:'-' and now its working fine